# global dimension of rings and projective (flat) dimension of modules

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, global-dimension

Let $R$ be ring such that every left $R$-module has finite projective dimension ( resp. finite injective dimension). Is the left global dimension of  $R$ finite?

Similarly, Let $R$ be ring such that every left $R$-module has finite flat dimension. Is the weak global dimension of  $R$ finite?

Comment: This might get a little more traction if it included a few definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $R$ has infinite left global dimension, then for every $n$ there is a left module $M_n$ with projective dimension greater than $n$. But then $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}M_n$ has infinite projective dimension.

The same argument works for weak dimension.